# I get an error when I'm trying to use Firefox In Debian Vagrant

Tags: firefox, debian, vagrant

I installed firefox in my debian vagrant using these commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
Add line in this file: deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

When I trying to use firefox I get error:

```
vagrant@packer-debian-7:~$ firefox -v
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libxul.so:
libXdamage.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

What can I do with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix error:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems it needs a library. Try to install it by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxdamage1
```